# Django ManyToMany Through not syncing or migrating

Tags: django, many-to-many, models, migrate, django-syncdb

I have this model (truncated here for brevity):

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="cooking")
    cost = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    summary = models.CharField(max_length=1024, default="A good dinner")

    diners = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Attendance',
    related_name="diners", blank=True)
```

When I sync it, the diners Field is completely ignored. It doesn't appear in the database and there is no error when running syncdb. It's as if it's not there. The User and Attendance tables are all fine.

I discovered this problem when trying to add this field with South, so I've tried that as an alternative too.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you already run syncdb fyrir Meal before you added the diners field?

Because syncdb will not alter existing tables as you can read here:

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)

Side note - I have not used south personally but I have used [Django evolution](http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/) while developing.

Edit:

After reading your comment I think I know what the problem is.

When using **through** with ManyToManyField Django doesn't add a field to that table, all the necessary information is in the **attendance** table.

Comment: No, I was using South migrations first which facilitates db alteration. I then scrapped the entire database to debug and ran syncdb afresh. Thanks though.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but it seems strange and I didn't notice that in the docs. I quite wanted this to be a denormalised field where I could simply check it for a tally. I guess I'll make a model manager on attendance or something. Thanks though!